# Extract json data contains list in values using Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I want to extract the data based on keys,

Ex: I want order values, How to get it in node js

```
const json = {"order": {
    "PRD_SHIRT_048": [
      "price",
      "productId",
      "quantity"
    ],
 "PRD_TOP_047": [
      "price",
      "productId",
      "quantity"
    ]
  }};
```

Comment: what is `order values` ?

Comment: What result you are expecting to get? Did you try to do it yourself (if so please attach your attempt)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly is your question, but if you want to access nested properties, you can do it like this:

```
json.order.PRD_SHIRT_048
```

This will return:

```
[
  "price",
  "productId",
  "quantity"
]
```

And if you want to get all the keys of order object, you can use `Object.keys(json.order)`
This will return

```
["PRD_SHIRT_048", "PRD_TOP_047"]
```